# Admob test ads is showing, But the real ads is not showing

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, admob

Need help.

The test ads is showing, But the real ads is not showing. It's been 4 days now.

My admob ad unit is new.

I need advice.

is this normal? Do I have to wait for more days?

```
    //Testing
    //string adID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712";

    //Live
    string adID = "MyLiveAdID";

    #if UNITY_ANDROID
    string adUnitId = adID;
    #elif UNITY_IOS
    string adUnitId = adID;
    #else
    string adUnitId = adID;
    #endif

    // Initialize an InterstitialAd.
    interstitial = new InterstitialAd(adUnitId);

    //Test
    //AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder()
    //.AddTestDevice(AdRequest.TestDeviceSimulator)    
    //.AddTestDevice("mytestdevice")  
    //.Build();

    AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();
```

Comment: At real device? Try on real device.

Comment: 4 days should be ample time for ads to start showing properly. Have you tried running it on your desired platform?

Comment: @YounghwaPark Yes tried it on real device. The test ads is showing.

But not the real ad unit.

Comment: @oxrock yup tried it also, I am using android phone. Everything seems fine on test ads. But not on real ads. :(

Comment: search addTestDevice() and comment it.

Comment: @YounghwaPark already did :(

  //Testing
//  string adID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712";

  //Live
  string adID = "M live AD ID";

   
  // Initialize an InterstitialAd.
  interstitial = new InterstitialAd(adUnitId);

  //test
  //AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder()
  //.AddTestDevice(AdRequest.TestDeviceSimulator)    
  //.AddTestDevice("MYTESTDEVICE")  
  //.Build();

              AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();

Comment: Why don't use ad ID?

Comment: I already Added my ad ID @YounghwaPark